# Does it make sense to use Codeigniter form helper?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think its easy to create form via only html and do not use form helper.
What is the advantage of using form helper?

Comment: It's a personal preference for me. I don't use it, but I understand why some would. Some PHP progammers don't want to have to deal with the HMTL and prefer to work with Array's, which the form helper uses heavily. It's a personal preference for you, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using form helper you obtain much benefits:

- Activation for xss/csrf protection
- Sanitize post data
- Multilanguage labels
- Validation
- Unique db validation
- Easy form modification
- Easy set form fields value

I recomend to you see:

[Form validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

[Form helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

[Lang helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/language_helper.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've found it helpful primarily for two reasons:

1. `form_open()` can do a lot for you, like resolving the action URL, adding CSRF hidden fields, etc.  If you decide later on that you want to enable/disable CSRF, it's a simple boolean switch if you used the function religiously.
2. `form_dropdown()` is a lifesaver, particularly if you want to repopulate an existing value, or provide a default.  I can think of very few times when it's easier to write this logic manually than provide an array of data and a default.

Beyond that, the other functions are gravy and depend on how you're using validation and such.

Because it's a **helper**, only use it if it *helps* you.

Answer (score 0):

They help you make forms. If you can do it, do it, I find any auto generating programs to be more harm then help. This is because they often use cheap styling to get what they want. Essentially they will never opt for the *best* solution rather the easiest.

Also, please read the FAQ as I don't think the community will like this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main benefit to using the form helper is that it can help with validation rules, sanitizing inputs, and adding protection from XSS.